# Ifelse statement for specific group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My DF has two dummy columns:

| Invested | ProgramParticipant |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |

The goal is to create a third dummy column, which only considers the rows that did not invest, and assigns a 1 if they participated in the program. If the row did not invest, a NA should be assigned. Ideally, it would look like this:

| Invested | ProgramParticipant | Invested&Participated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | NA |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | NA |
| 0 | 0 | NA |

I tried working with standard ifelse statements, or with DPLYR's casewhen, but I cannot seem to fix the NA assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
ifelse(Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 1, 1,
       ifelse(Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 0, 0, NA))
```

Comment: That's it. I did not know you could use a second ifelse statement for the 0. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(InvestednParticipated = if_else(Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 1, 1,
                                              if_else(Invested == 0, NA_real_, 0)))

  Invested ProgramParticipant InvestednParticipated
1        1                  0                     0
2        0                  0                    NA
3        1                  1                     1
4        1                  0                     0
5        0                  1                    NA
6        0                  0                    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `case_when` to avoid the confusion of nested `ifelse`s:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(InvestedParticipated = 
           case_when(Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 1 ~ 1,
                     Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 0 ~ 0,
                     Invested == 0 ~ NA_real_))
```

output

```r
  Invested ProgramParticipant InvestedParticipated
1        1                  0                    0
2        0                  0                   NA
3        1                  1                    1
4        1                  0                    0
5        0                  1                   NA
6        0                  0                   NA
```

`case_when` sets to NA cases that are not matched, so you could even do:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(InvestedParticipated = 
           case_when(Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 1 ~ 1,
                     Invested == 1 & ProgramParticipant == 0 ~ 0))
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify what happens to unmatched cases with `TRUE ~ NA`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a nested `ifelse()`. A single `ifelse()` is enough.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(res = ifelse(Invested == 0, NA, Invested + ProgramParticipant - 1))

#   Invested ProgramParticipant res
# 1        1                  0   0
# 2        0                  0  NA
# 3        1                  1   1
# 4        1                  0   0
# 5        0                  1  NA
# 6        0                  0  NA
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Invested = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ProgramParticipant = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple indexing:

```
DF$InvestedParticipated <- with(DF, c(NA, 0, 1)[Invested*(ProgramParticipant + 1) + 1])
```